# cloudinstall.config.ConfigException: Unable to load environments file. Is juju bootstrapped

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm trying to install openstack using autopilot

after run sudo openstack-install 
fill the information

```
landscapecreds:
  admin_email: email@emai.com
  admin_name: admin
  maas_apikey: xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
  maas_server: 172.16.0.1/MAAS/
  system_email: email@emai.com
maascreds:
  api_host: 172.16.206.55/MAAS/
  api_key:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
openstack_password: xxxx
openstack_release: juno
```

it's shown there are no ready system the hang .
I've delete ~/.cloud-install folder

and try again run openstack-install command
after enter the api key it's give me blunk page 
below is what commands.log give to me

```
[DEBUG • 07-27 13:37:50] • cloudinstall.config • (config.py, juju_env, 201)]
   Querying juju env in /home/ubuntu/.cloud-install/juju/environments/maas.jenv
[DEBUG • 07-27 13:37:50] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, global_exchandler, 63)]
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/openstack-status", line 109, in <module>
    core.start()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/core.py", line 620, in start
    self.initialize()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/core.py", line 148, in initialize
    self.authenticate_juju()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/core.py", line 131, in authenticate_juju
    if not len(self.config.juju_env['state-servers']) > 0:
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/config.py", line 207, in juju_env
    raise ConfigException('Unable to load environments file. Is '
cloudinstall.config.ConfigException: Unable to load environments file. Is juju bootstrapped?

[INFO  • 07-27 13:37:50] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, cleanup, 91)]
   Cleanup, saving latest config object.
[DEBUG • 07-27 13:37:50] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, cleanup, 97)]
   Attempting to reset the terminal
```

Comment: what version of the installer are you running? maas version and juju version as well.

Comment: maas is 1.8 juju is juju --version
1.24.2-trusty-amd64

Comment: NOTE:
:~/.cloud-install$ sudo ls /home/osadmin/.cloud-install/juju/environments/maas.jenv
ls: cannot access /home/osadmin/.cloud-install/juju/environments/maas.jenv: No such file or directory
;
 ls juju/
environments  ssh

Comment: So it looks like the bootstrap never completed. Do you see a machine being allocated when you run the installer initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise where is my issue

```
maas_server: 172.16.0.1/MAAS
```

I've given the IP of MAAS follow with **/MAAS**
to fix it

```
#to remove the proxy configuration 
http_proxy=
https_proxy
sudo mv ./.cloud-install ./.cloud-install-backup
sudo openstack-install
```

when ask for MAAS IP give only the IP

NOTE: if you are working behind proxy remove proxy configuration